# Can't execute external script from zabbix

Tags: python, zabbix

I'm trying to execute script from zabbix ui. I put my script to '/usr/lib/zabbix/externalscripts' folder. The script's name is "check_ssl.py". When I connect to server and go to that folder and execute the script manually - it works, but  when I try to execute it from zabbix's ui - it throws an error :

```
"Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/zabbix/externalscripts/check_ssl.py", line 14, in <module>
    ACCESS_KEY = conf('ACCESS_KEY')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/decouple.py", line 243, in __call__
    return self.config(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/decouple.py", line 105, in __call__
    return self.get(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/decouple.py", line 90, in get
    raise UndefinedValueError('{} not found. Declare it as envvar or define a default value.'.format(option))
decouple.UndefinedValueError: ACCESS_KEY not found. Declare it as envvar or define a default value."
```

ACCESS_KEY variable is declared and set as env. variable. Does anyone know why it throws this error?

Comment: it provides a hint for the solution; `ACCESS_KEY not found. Declare it as envvar or define a default value` can you try that?

Answer (score 0):

The service environment is different from other users' env, see https://serverfault.com/questions/413397/how-to-set-environment-variable-in-systemd-service

Edit the service with `systemctl edit zabbix-server` and add `Environment="ACCESS_KEY=your_access_key"` in the `[Service]` section.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create the script with Scope: Action Operation, Type: Script, Execute on: Zabbix agent (i've done it like that and works fine)
2. On commands insert the command, example `python3 /home/suppor/python_scripts/customer/restart_apache.py`
3. On Actions create one, select the condition (may be the trigger when to run the script), on Operation tab add the operation to run the script created

It works fine. You must allow remote commands on the zabbix agent